# Accepting both Timestamp type and DateTime type at the same DTO property in controller in .NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, serialization

I have DTO model received by the controller with given properties

```
{
    public string Name;
    public DateTime DateProperty;
}
```

My question is, if is there any way for DateProperty to be correctly serialized as both **DateTime** and **TimeStamp** from the request, for example when I send given POST request:

```
"Name": "Sample Name",
"DateProperty": "1583524428"
```

I recive following error: 
*Could not convert string to DateTime: 1583524428. Path 'end', line 4, position 20.".*
 Obviously, when I send correct request(below) everything is okay.

```
"Name": "Sample Name",
"DateProperty": "2020-02-21T10:25"
```

Is there any way to detect if **DatePropery** is TimeStamp, and if so convert it to **DateTime** before middleware returns conversion error?

**EDIT**
I have resovled this problem by implementing DateTimeConverter

```
   public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset>
    {

        public override DateTimeOffset ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, DateTimeOffset existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(reader.Value.ToString());
        }

  private static DateTimeOffset ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(string timestamp)
        {
            DateTimeOffset origin = new DateTimeOffset();
            origin = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(Int64.Parse(timestamp));
            return origin;
        }
    }
```

And in Startup.cs

```
  services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {

           options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(newDateTimeConverter());

            })
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` type wouldn't know if you are sending a timestamp or a date time value in a cultural format. One way I've overcome this is by making the property a string and adding a second read-only property of type DateTime and do the math my self.

```cs
public class MyDTO {
    public string dateProperty {get; set;}
    public DateTime? DatePropertyAsDateTime {
        get {
            if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateProperty)) return null;
            double nixTimeStamp = 0;
            //see if the DateProperty is a double number.
            if(Double.TryParse(dateProperty, out nixTimeStamp))
            {
                DateTime ts = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                return ts.AddSeconds(nixTimeStamp);
            }
            //If not, just try to parse it to DateTime.
            return DateTime.Parse(dateProperty);
        }
    }
}
```